# Binary Snap [AIO 2015]

Tags: c++

This is a question from the Australian Informatics Olympiad

The question is:

Have you ever heard of Melodramia, my friend? It is a land of forbidden forests and boundless swamps, of sprinting heroes and dashing heroines. And it is home to two dragons, Rose and Scarlet, who, despite their competitive streak, are the best of friends.

Rose and Scarlet love playing Binary Snap, a game for two players. The game is played with a deck of cards, each with a numeric label from 1 to N. There are two cards with each possible label, making 2N cards in total. The game goes as follows:

Rose shuffles the cards and places them face down in front of Scarlet.
Scarlet then chooses either the top card, or the second-from-top card from the deck and reveals it.
Scarlet continues to do this until the deck is empty. If at any point the card she reveals has the same label as the previous card she revealed, the cards are a Dragon Pair, and whichever dragon shouts `Snap!' first gains a point.
After many millenia of playing, the dragons noticed that having more possible Dragon Pairs would often lead to a more exciting game. It is for this reason they have summoned you, the village computermancer, to write a program that reads in the order of cards in the shuffled deck and outputs the maximum number of Dragon Pairs that the dragons can find.

I'm not sure how to solve this. I thought of something which is wrong(choosing the maximum over all cards, when compared with its previous occurence for each card)

Here's my code as of now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 ifstream fin("snapin.txt");
ofstream fout("snapout.txt");
int n;
fin>>n;
int arr[(2*n)+1];
for(int i=0;i<2*n;i++){
    fin>>arr[i];
}
int dp[(2*n) +1];
int maxi = 0;
int pos[n+1];
for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++){
    pos[i] = -1;
}

int count = 0;
for(int i=2;i<(2*n)-2;i++){
   if(pos[arr[i]] == -1){
       pos[arr[i]] = i;
   }else{
       dp[i] = pos[arr[i]]+1;
       maxi = max(dp[i],maxi);
   }

   dp[i] = max(dp[i],maxi);
}

fout<<dp[2*n -1];
}
```

Comment: "Dragon Pair" is most likely a hint at "Dynamic Programming", the method you need to use in your solution in order to avoid having your program run longer than the universe.

Comment: My current code is a sort of dp solution but isn't the right one. I'm not sure about how I should progress

Comment: Have you ever seen Viterbi's algorithm for convolution code reception?  A similar trellis method will work here, because at step T, paths may differ in the card just drawn and the card on top of the deck, but the rest of the deck is sure to be the cards originally at depths [T + 1, 2*N].  Thus there will be opportunities for trellis convergence.

Comment: I'm going to have to look into this, Thanks!

Comment: So I tried reading up on it online, but I don't understand anything. Could you help me out please?

Comment: I know a number of different approaches to explaining it, but I need to know which of them would build on what you already know.  Are you familiar with any of the following concepts and fields?  Branch & bound (integer programming), Domination (game theory), Markov chains, Minimum Spanning Tree (graph theory)

Comment: I don't really know any of them :/

Comment: Ok, I can't really take time from work for such a long exposition, but I'll take another look this evening.

Comment: Thank you! I'm interested in learning more

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's get some basic measurements of the problem out of the way first:

- There are 2N cards.  1 card is drawn at a time, without replacement.  Therefore there are 2N draws, taking the deck from size 2N (before the first draw) to size 0 (after the last draw).
- The final draw takes place from a deck of size 1, and must take the last remaining card.
- The 2N-1 preceding draws have deck size 2N, ... 3, 2.  For each of these you have a choice between the top two cards.  2N-1 decisions, each with 2 possibilities.
- The brute force search space is therefore 2<sup>2N-1</sup>.

That is exponential growth, every optimization scientist's favorite sort of challenge.

- If N is small, say 20, the brute force method needs to search "only" a trillion possibilities, which you can get done in a few thousand seconds on a readily available PC that does a few billion operations per second (each solution takes more than one CPU instruction to check).
- In N is not quite as small, perhaps 100, the brute force method is akin to breaking the encryption on government secrets.

Not happy with the brute force approach then?  I'm not either.

---

Before we get to the optimal solution, let’s take a break to explore what the Markov assumption is and what it means for us.  It shows up in different fields using different verbiage, but I’ll just paraphrase it in a way that is particularly useful for this problem involving gameplay choices:

## Markov Assumption

> A process is Markov if and only if **The choices available to you in the future depend only on what you have now, and not how you got it**.

A bad but often used real-world example is the stock market.  Not only do taxation differences between short-term and long-term capital gains make history important in a small way, but investors do trend analysis and remember what stocks have done before, which affects future behavior in a big way.
A better example, especially for StackOverflow, is that of Turing machines and computer processors.  What your program does next depends on the current instruction pointer and the contents of memory, but not the history of memory that’s since been overwritten.  But there are many more.  As we’ll see shortly, the Binary Snap problem can be formulated as Markov.

---

Now let’s talk about what makes the Markov assumption so important.  For that, we’ll use the Travelling Salesman Problem.  No, the Travelling International Salesman Problem.  Still too messy.  Let’s try the “Travelling International Salesman with a Single-Entry Visa Problem”.  But we’ll go through all three of them briefly:

## Travelling Salesman Problem

> A salesman has to visit potential buyers in N cities.  Plan an itinerary for the salesman which minimizes the total cost of visiting all N cities (variations: at least once / exactly once), given a matrix a<sub>*j,k*</sub> which is the cost of travel from city *j* to city *k*.
>   Another variation is whether the starting city is predetermined or not.

## Travelling International Salesman Problem

> The cities the salesman needs to visit are split between two (or more) nations.  A subset of the cities have border crossings and have travel options to all cities.  The other cities can only reach cities which are either in the same country or are border-equipped.
>   Alternatively, instead of cities along the border, use cities with international airports.  Won’t make a difference in the end.
>   The cost matrix for this problem looks rather like the flag of the Dominican Republic.  Travel between interior cities of country A is permitted, as is travel between interior cities of country B (blue fields).  Border cities connect with interior and border cities in both countries (white cross).  And direct travel between an interior city of country A and one of country B is impossible (red areas).

[image: Dominican Republic flag for illustration of block matrix]

## Travelling International Salesman with a Single-Entry Visa

> Now not only does the salesman need to visit cities in both countries, but he can only cross the border once.
>   (For travel fanatics, assume he starts in a third country and has single-entry visas for both countries, so he can’t visit some of A, all of B, then return to A for the rest).

Let’s look at an extremely simple case first: Only one border city.  We’ll use one additional trick, the one from proof by induction: We assume that all problems smaller than the current one can be solved.
It should be fairly obvious that the Markov assumption holds when the salesman reaches the border city.  No matter what path he took through country A, he has exactly the same choice of paths through country B.
But there’s a really important point here: Any path through country A ending at the border and any path through country B starting at the border, can be combined into a feasible full itinerary.  If we have two full itineraries *x* and *y*, and *x* spent more money in country A than *y* did, then even if *x* has a lower total cost than the total cost of *y*, we can plan a path better than both, using the portion of *y* in country A and the portion of *x* in country B.  I’m going to call that “splicing”.  **The Markov assumption lets us do it, by making all roads leading to the border interchangeable!**
In fact, we can look just at the cities of country A, pick the best of all routes to the border, and forget about all the other options as soon as (in our plan) the salesman steps across into B.
This means instead of having factorial(N<sub>A</sub>) * factorial(N<sub>B</sub>) routes to look at, there’s only factorial(N<sub>A</sub>) + factorial(N<sub>B</sub>).  Which is pretty much factorial(N<sub>A</sub>) times better.  Wow, is this Markov thing helpful or what?

Ok, that was too easy.  Let’s mess it all up by having N<sub>AB</sub> border cities instead of just one.  Now if I have a path *x* which costs less in country B and a path *y* which costs less in country A, but they cross the border in different cities, I can’t just splice them together.  So I have to keep track of all the paths through all the cities again, right?
Not exactly.  What if, instead of throwing away all the paths through country A except the best *y* path, I actually keep one path ending in each border city (the lowest cost of all paths ending in the same border city).  Now, for any path *x* I look at in country B, I have a path *y<sub>endpt(x)</sub>* that uses the same border city, to splice it with.  So I have to solve the country A and country B partitions each N<sub>AB</sub> times to find the best splice of a complete itinerary, for total work of N<sub>AB</sub> factorial(N<sub>A</sub>) + N<sub>AB</sub> factorial(N<sub>B</sub>) which is still way better than factorial(N<sub>A</sub>) * factorial(N<sub>B</sub>).

---

Enough development of tools.  Let’s get back to the dragons, since they are they are subtle and quick to anger and I don’t want to be eaten or burnt to a crisp.

I claim that at any step T of the Binary Snap game, if we consider our “location” a pair of (card just drawn, card on top of deck), the Markov assumption will hold.  These are the only things that determine our future options.  All the cards below the top one in the deck must be in the same order no matter what we did before.  And for knowing whether to count a *Snap!* with the next card, we need to know the last one taken.  And that’s it!
Furthermore, there are N possible labels on the card last drawn, and N possible for the top card on the deck, for a total of N<sup>2</sup> “border cities”.  As we start playing the game, there are two choices on the first turn, two on the second, two on the third, so we start out with 2<sup>T</sup> possible game states (and a count of Snap!s for each).  But by the pigeonhole principle, when 2<sup>T</sup> > N<sup>2</sup>, some of these plays must end in exactly the same game state (“border city”) as each other, and when that happens, we only need to keep the "dominating" one that got the best score on the way there.
Final complexity bound: 2*N timesteps, from no more than N<sup>2</sup> game states, with 2 draw choices at each, equals an upper limit of 4*N<sup>3</sup> simulated draws.
And that means the same trillion calculations that allowed us to do N=20 with the brute force method, now permit right around N=8000.
That makes the dragons happy, which makes us alive and well.

---

Implementation note: Since the challenge didn’t ask for the order of draws, but just the highest attainable number of snaps, all you data to keep track of in addition to the initial ordering of the cards is the time, T, and a 2-dimensional array (N rows, N columns) of the best score you can have and reach that state at time T.

---

Real world applications: If you take this approach and apply it to a digital radio (fixed uniform bit timing, discrete signal levels) receiving a signal using a convolutional error-correcting code, you have the Viterbi decoder.  If you apply it to acquired medical data, with variable timing intervals and continuous signal levels, and add some other gnarly math, you get [my doctoral project](http://www.sparxeng.com/viva).

Comment: So I spent the last few hours trying to figure this out but I'm still confused. I understood up until the questions provided, but I don't understand their answers and what you meant in how to implent/solve this problem(I get how by definition this can be solved using Markov's, but I don't understand how to actually solve it)

Comment: @BenRitmico: Ok maybe I spent so much time talking about the overall proof I skipped over the basic step, what would be the induction step in a proof by induction, or the recursion formula.  If I gave you the list corresponding to the initial state of the deck, and told you the game state is "Time T (that's the number of draws so far), Card *x* was last drawn, card *y* on top of the deck, and *z* Snap!s have been found so far" can you calculate the two game states which are reachable? (corresponding to the two choices of "draw top" or "draw second-to-top")

Comment: would it be something like if card y or the second to top card is the same as card x, increment z?

Comment: Something like that, but I want you to actually write out what the two future states are, because your code needs to calculate them both as well.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by two future states?